# Generating Images from maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, maps, leaflet

How do you capture an image of a user generated map, like one created using Leaflet.js?

**Here is my example:**

- I have a [website](https://www.arelplane.com/@arelenglish) that generates a map.
- I want to save an image of that map

  - e.g. when the user shares their profile, the preview image is of their map.

I know facebook, Strava, and most other services show images of a user map in their news feeds instead of showing interactive maps.

**The problem**

The map is generated client side, so grabbing an image of the map serverside isn't possible

**Possible Solution**

Once a map is generated, use PhantomJS to capture a screenshot of the map, and crop out the rest of the website.

**Question**

Since this is such a common thing to do, is anyone aware of a better or more standard way of grabbing these screenshots? I've seen things like the mapbox static API, but that doesn't capture the custom pins and line features on my maps.

I'm using rails for the back end.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your map to be able to read the url params and set its state from it. When the user changes something on the map, the map's state is saved as url parameters and then send it/store it on the server for PhantomJS to generate it.
E.g.

```
&coords=123.123,10.123,54.54,45.11&zoom_level=5&....
```

Comment: Some maps have 10's of thousands of values, so to make the map layer, I generate a GeoJSON object, and save that. I'm assuming I'm going to have to create a small node app that uses phantomJS to go an take a screenshot every time a user creates/updates a map.